# video playbackrate auto increment on interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm trying to increment video.playbackRate automatically in every 2 seconds.

here's my code:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
            for (i=1;i<2;i++){
                video.playbackRate += 1;
                console.log(video.playbackRate);
                }
                }, 2000);
            }
```

but it goes to infinity. How can i improve that?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/abt1du6j/) here

Comment: It will go to infinity if clearInterval() is not called. When do you want to stop the increment ? Any specific upperlimit or something like that?

Comment: on something like that if(speed=='111'){
    clearInterval(a);
   }

Comment: I feel that the logic of that fiddle is completely wrong. rethink . or give more info on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You have function A that repeats every 50ms. If variable speed is set as 66, the function A triggers function B that repeats itself every 2s. During each run of B playback rate is incremented.
So, write that clearInterval code in function A itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you want to stop that function, use `clearInterval`

```
var f = window.setInterval(function(){
    ...

// Enough, let's stop the repetition
clearInterval(f);
```